# Hibernate L2C misses but no query executed

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

Here is an example hibernate statistics:

```
11:24:26,518 INFO  
[org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener] 
(default task-61) Session Metrics {
    0 nanoseconds spent acquiring 0 JDBC connections;

    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    925824 nanoseconds spent performing 64 L2C hits;
    97418 nanoseconds spent performing 2 L2C misses;
    799458 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 62 entities and 0 collections);
    6950 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

There are two L2C misses but where is no database query? My understanding is that if there is a L2C miss there should be a query to database. How does this happen?